# Нестыковка версии джавы

Tags: java, weblogic

Использую Weblogic а там версия джавы 1,6 , `Path()` и `readAllBytes` методы с 7 джавы хотим использовать но компилятор ругается, можно как то решить это?

Comment: совершенно непонятно, что это у вас за методы. Полный путь указывайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: byte[] bytes =  Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get()); вот этот метод к примеру

Comment: А смысл? Не проще ли найти их реализацию, тем паче, есть open-jdk и реализовать у себя в проекте отдельным классом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы то ни было - вам нужно искать альтернативные пути решения. 
Отличия пакет .nio (new input/output) - который вам нужен, отличается архитектурой и даже многими тонкостями реализации, но, по сути, решает те же самые задачи, что и .io. Врядли составит большого труда перенести логику на java.io

Так же неплохой альтернативой для вас будет библиотека Google Guava (там много интересных и удобных инструментов, в том числе впоследствии включенных в стандартный инструментарий java (например, Optional был включен в Java 8)).
Вот, к примеру, com.google.common.io.Files.toByteArray - то, что вам нужно.